# Python CSV Module behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python, csv

I have wrote a variable to a text file with the following format:

```
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
```

I want to delimit these variables using the following code where 'data2' is the string being written:

```
csv.register_dialect('sas', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='sas')
                writer.writerows(data2)
```

The values above are produced by submitting a url statement of the following format:

```
www.finance.yahoo.com&s=var1+var2+var3+var4+var5&f=metric
```

However the output I am getting is like this:

```
v
a
l
1

v
a
l
2

v
a
l
3
```

etc...

I have tried using '.QUOTE_ALL' but that just repeats the above but in quotes. I want the final output to be:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4
```

Please note that the actual values of varx could be anything from multiple word character strings to numeric data with ',' and '.' characters in, so I won't be able to use them as delimters, nor space.

The relevant code up to where I use code from the csv module is below:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import json
import csv


myurls2 = {}                     #define dictionary
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x)
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)

#define dictionary values from text file (URL strings)

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f:
            myurls2[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')            
            #print("myurls_" + str(strvar1) + "_" + str(strvar2) + "=", myurls2[x,y])
            #print(myurls2[x,y])

#use parallel processing to submit there url strings

URLS = myurls2.values()

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(key, url, timeout):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    return conn.readall()


# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, key, url, 60): (key, url)
                 for key, url in myurls2.items()}
    c = 0

    #create file names from dictionary keys and do some formatting

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        key, url = future_to_url[future]    
        a = url.rsplit("=", 1)[-1]
        uuu = key
        uu = str(uuu)
        uv = uu[1:-1]
        uva,uvb = uv.split(",")
        uvbb = uvb.lstrip()
        u = uva + "_" + uvbb + "_"
        u = u.rstrip()
        print("key =", u)
        c += 1


        #if statement to define a goes here

        #some more formatting for the filename

        print("a = ", a)
        print('b =', b)
        print('c =', c)
        filename = "%s" % (b)
        filename = filename.lstrip()
        filename2 = u
        filepath = "C:\\Python33\\Stock Data\\" + str(filename2) + "NASDAQ_" + str(filename) + ".txt"

        #pass content returned from url submission to text file via CSV module

        data = future.result()

        try:
            csv.register_dialect('sas', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                #writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='sas')
                #writer.writerow(data)
            do json processing here
```

Can anyone see what the issue is here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `writer.writerow()` **singular** (not `writer.writerows()`, plural), and pass in a *list* of values

```
writer.writerow([var1, var2, var3, var4])
```

Don't pass in a string; the `csv` module deals in *rows*; each row is a list or tuple of columns.

You passed in a single string to the `writer.writerows()` method. It expects a list of rows; it essentially does:

```
def writerows(self, rows):
    for row in rows:
        self.writerow(row)
```

Looping over a string gives you individual characters, so if `data2` is a single string the above passes those character one by one to `self.writerow()`. The `writer.writerow()` method expects a sequence of columns; a one-character string is still a sequence, but contains just one element, that single character. Thus, each row written to the file consists of single characters.

The `csv` module is perfectly capable of handling columns with commas in them; it'll correctly quote such values for you.

Comment: @martijnpieters...its now producing an output that looks like this: 34,38,110,98,115,112, however this has no resemblance to the data as it should look?

Comment: @user3045351: Then write different data to the CSV. The module writes to disk what you give it.

Comment: the data i am outputting without using this method is fine apart from the fact that it isn't delimited. when i use this method i get an output that looks nothing like what i would expect to see without using the import csv module. i want to convert val1 val2 val3 to val1, val2, val3...

Comment: @user3045351: Without more code I cannot help you at all; if you get the wrong data in your file, then you didn't pass in the right values. That's all I can say without seeing how you produce values or pass them to `writer.writerow()`.

Comment: @martijnpieters...I have amended my question to show some abridged (relevant) code...

Comment: @user3045351: I see several potential problems here: `concurrent.futures` can be returning data as threats complete, resulting in a different order from what you expected. You are writing the data *directly* to the CSV file without processing, as one string.

Comment: @user3045351: my advice: simplify this down to **just** downloading **one** URL, without the `concurrent.futures` library, and getting that data written to a CSV in a form you want. Only then add in the rest of your code. If you have problems with that still, ask new questions about *focused* problems. Produce small test scripts to work out your ideas and understanding first.